# Map JSON Entries to Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple class `Pet`:

```
public class Pet{
   private name;
   private age;
}
```

and `HashMap<String,<Pet>>` - the `String` value is a child's name.
In html file I get this hashmap in Json, for example:

`{"Jon":[{"name":"dog","age":5},{"name":"cat","age":4},{"name":"parrot","age":3}],"Paul":[{"name":"parrot","age":3}]}`

There are two `select` in my html, the first one represents child's name and the second is for pets:

```
       <select id="Child">
           <option value="Jon">Jon</option>
           <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
        </select>
        <select id="Pet">
        </select>
```

I want to select `child's name` and then put into second `select` name of `Pets` for this child. I know that it is impossible to load all data  and then use something like 'hide' and 'show'. So what is the best way to `decode` my `Json` to some arrays and then dynamically add it to clean `select`?

@Update
my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
// Parse the JSON string into a proper object
        let data = JSON.parse('{"Jon":[{"name":"dog","age":5},{"name":"cat","age":4},{"name":"parrot","age":3}],"Paul":[{"name":"parrot","age":3}]}');

        // References to both SELECT elements
        let child = document.getElementById('Child');
        let pet = document.getElementById('Pet');

        // An event listener to handle changes to the child-select
        child.addEventListener('change', function () {
            // Attempt to look-up the selected value in our JSON
            let option = data[this.value];

            // Proceed only if a match (with depth) is found
            if (option && option.length) {
                // Create a fragment, and add option elements
                let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                option.forEach(function (item) {
                    let entry = document.createElement("option");
                    entry.value = item.name;
                    entry.textContent = item.name;
                    fragment.appendChild(entry);
                });

                // Clear the pet-select of any values, re-populate
                pet.innerHTML = '';
                pet.appendChild(fragment);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="Child">
          <option value="Jon">Jon</option>
          <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
        </select id="Pet">
        <select id="Pet">
        </select>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, if `#Child` exists in your JSON file, you would like the `name` property from the corresponding objects to be listed as values for `#Pet`?

Comment: that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the following, but it may work *as written*. See inline comments for further explanation:

```
// Only proceed once the DOM has been constructed
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // Parse the JSON string into a proper object
    let data = JSON.parse('{"Jon":[...],"Paul":[...]}');

    // References to both SELECT elements
    let child = document.getElementById('Child');
    let pet = document.getElementById('Pet');

    // An event listener to handle changes to the child-select
    if (child && pet) {
        child.addEventListener('change', function () {
            // Attempt to look-up the selected value in our JSON
            let option = data[this.value];

            // Proceed only if a match (with depth) is found
            if (option && option.length) {
                // Create a fragment, and add option elements
                let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                option.forEach(function (item) {
                    let entry = document.createElement("option");
                    entry.value = item.name;
                    entry.textContent = item.name;
                    fragment.appendChild(entry);
                });

                // Clear the pet-select of any values, re-populate
                pet.innerHTML = '';
                pet.appendChild(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: @littlewombat Your JavaScripts runs before the `<body>` is even created. So the calls to `getElementById` fail to find the elements. Either put the `<script>` at the bottom of your `<body>`, or wrap it all in a `DOMContentLoaded` handler.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to link the Pets select to their owner you can use the JQuery Chained plugin

```js
    var values = {
        "Jon": [{"name": "dog", "age": 5}, {"name": "cat", "age": 4}, {"name": "parrot", "age": 3}],
        "Paul": [{"name": "parrot", "age": 3}]
    }
    $(function () {
        for (var key in values) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values[key].length; i++) {
                $('#Pet').append($('<option>',
                    {
                        value: values[key][i].name,
                        text: values[key][i].name,
                        class: key
                    }));
            }
        }
        $("#Pet").chained("#Child");
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-chained/1.0.0/jquery.chained.js"></script>
    <select id="Child">
    <option value="Jon">Jon</option>
    <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Pet">
    </select>
```